# Cordova FileOpener2 on SD card

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-sdcard, fileopener2

I'm struggling for hours now to read and write to SD card on Android using cordova, since `cordova.file.externalRootFolder` just gives back `file:///storage/emulated/0` (Android 6.0+), which is the same as the internal disk. 
But I got that working now, so I got `file:///storage/7EC0-0CEC/`, which is the root folder of the SD-card I inserted into my smartphone. 
I still can't create folders on that root, but I can use the application folder `file:///storage/7EC0-0CEC/Android/data/{app-name}/files/..` to store my files. 
Now with the [file-opener2](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2)-plugin I can't open the File. The Error I get is:

`Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/7EC0-0CEC/Android/data/{app-name}/files/test.txt`

Any suggestions? Did I miss to configure something?

Comment: Yes. Your app can write to `file:///storage/7EC0-0CEC/Android/data/{app-name}/files/..`. Its the app specific directory on a micro SD card. The rest of the card is not writable for your app. Thats how Google wanted it.

Comment: `Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/7EC0-0CEC/Android/data/{app-name}/files/test.txt` That is not a message i would expect from a file picker. It looks more a message form a file provider.

Comment: file-opener2 is not a "file picker". Like the name says it's a plugin to open files external (Android Dialog, choose the app you want to open the given file with)